# Cassandra CQL3 slice query issue - How to slice

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table created using `CQL3` with:

```
create table compositetest(m_id ascii,i_id int,l_id ascii,body ascii,
  PRIMARY KEY(m_id,i_id,l_id));
```

Inserted some random data:

```
cqlsh:testkeyspace1> insert into compositetest(m_id,i_id,l_id,body) VALUES ('m1',1,'l1','b1');
cqlsh:testkeyspace1> insert into compositetest(m_id,i_id,l_id,body) VALUES ('m2',2,'l2','b2');
cqlsh:testkeyspace1> insert into compositetest(m_id,i_id,l_id,body) VALUES ('m1',2,'l2','b2');
cqlsh:testkeyspace1> insert into compositetest(m_id,i_id,l_id,body) VALUES ('m2',1,'l1','b1');
cqlsh:testkeyspace1> insert into compositetest(m_id,i_id,l_id,body) VALUES ('m3',3,'l1','b1');
cqlsh:testkeyspace1> insert into compositetest(m_id,i_id,l_id,body) VALUES ('m3',2,'l2','b2');
cqlsh:testkeyspace1> insert into compositetest(m_id,i_id,l_id,body) VALUES ('m3',1,'l2','b2');
cqlsh:testkeyspace1> select * from compositetest;

 m_id | i_id | l_id | body
------+------+------+------
   m1 |    1 |   l1 |   b1
   m1 |    2 |   l2 |   b2
   m2 |    1 |   l1 |   b1
   m2 |    2 |   l2 |   b2
   m3 |    1 |   l2 |   b2
   m3 |    2 |   l2 |   b2
   m3 |    3 |   l1 |   b1
```

When I do a query

```
cqlsh:testkeyspace1> select * from compositetest where i_id<=3 limit 3;

 m_id | i_id | l_id | body
------+------+------+------
   m1 |    1 |   l1 |   b1
   m1 |    2 |   l2 |   b2
   m2 |    1 |   l1 |   b1
```

Now if I want to get the next 3 rows

```
cqlsh:testkeyspace1> ?
```

Was trying to write CQL for slice range (not sure if it can be done)

My CQLSh shows the Socket is closed and I see the error

```
TSocket read 0 bytes
```

On the server side I see the following error:

```
ERROR [Thrift:3] 2012-08-12 15:15:24,414 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java (line 204) Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement$Restriction.setBound(SelectStatement.java:1277)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement$RawStatement.updateRestriction(SelectStatement.java:1151)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement$RawStatement.prepare(SelectStatement.java:1001)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.getStatement(QueryProcessor.java:215)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.process(QueryProcessor.java:121)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.execute_cql_query(CassandraServer.java:1237)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$execute_cql_query.getResult(Cassandra.java:3542)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$execute_cql_query.getResult(Cassandra.java:3530)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

How do I get the next 3 rows, regarding the exception on server side, I will file a bug. The CQLSh closed and I have to now exit and reconnect

Comment: With Hector, I could use DynamicComposite and provide a start and a end range and get the next set of columns, with CQL3 I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: Is your problem the traceback and the connection failure? It's hard to determine what caused those if you don't provide the actual query that caused them. If you just want to know how to do paging over a slice range, you could either wait for [CASSANDRA-4415](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4415) or break up your query into multiple steps, limiting results manually. Yeah, it kind of sucks.

Comment: I tried to break the query, but didn't work for me.

Comment: I tried to break the query, but didn't work for me. Note that the composite column is made of 2 parts, with hector you specify the start range as the last returned column, while you keep the end range same (LESS THAN EQUAL).With cql3 I cant do that. 1> select * from <cf> where i_id <=3 limit 3; -> this would return 3 records. so in CQL3 you cant do an equilvalent -> select * from <cf> where i_id=1 and l_id='l1' and i_id <=3 (this just isn't logical). This will make cqlsh close connection.

Comment: Why would you want to try to do "`i_id=1 and (...) i_id <= 3`" ? What is the actual overall query that you want to fetch with paging?

Comment: lets suppose I have 100 columns in that wide row. I want to be able to get 10 at a time, and every time get the next 10 columns with the first column being the last column from previous batch(which is possible with thrift/hector) until the condition is met. The overall query would be select * from <cf> where i_id < [some number] LIMIT 10; The second query will have to be modified to get next 10.With thrift/hector the last row of the previous query becomes the start range of the next query, while the end range remains the same until there are no more rows to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

CQL has what is called 'auto paging' since CQL2 and above. In short, what you are describing is already handled by the driver.

When your code requests a new row, the server only sends the next row of the query, not the whole result. Similarly you can tell it to give you back how ever many rows you want.

In DB terms, you execute a query, get a cursor back. Then you tell the cursor to fetch N number of rows, which the server sends back (not the whole result set).

Once there are no more rows to return, cursor is finished.

In cqlsh you get up to 1k rows displayed automatically IIRC as it traverses the cursor up to that point.